# @Configuration annotation can't be resolved.

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

What's wrong with my dependency? I'm new to Spring and Maven projects.
org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration is totally missing even though org.springframework.context.annotation package exists.

Comment: If you're new to Spring and Maven, use [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io) to autogenerate your project skeleton for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the spring-context dependency.

Spring provides a bill of materials (BOM) that makes all this much easier. You can find it at [org.springframework:spring-framework-bom](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22spring-framework-bom%22).

Comment: I'm watching a tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4LovobJXoU. There is no spring-context there I guessed. But you're right. It works. Thank you so much. :D

Comment: how about @AutoWired?

Comment: That's in spring-beans. Just use the bom, that includes everything you need. Even better, use Spring Boot. That includes a better bom, and wrapper jars.

Comment: I"ll try Spring Boot after current tutorial. It seems pretty awesome since it prepares everything for development.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: how about @AutoWired ?

Comment: `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`